# In SpecFlow generated files: Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.468 vs. 4.0.30319.239 - where does it come from?

Tags: .net, runtime, specflow

I developing on Windows Server 2008 (not R2) using VS 2010 Pro. I updated [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org) on my machine to [version 1.8.1](https://github.com/downloads/techtalk/SpecFlow/SpecFlowSetup_v1.8.1.msi) today and chose to `Regenerate Feature Files` in Visual Studio by right-clicking on a project that contains some SpecFlow feature file.

With the last version, 1.7.1, after doing that I got the following in the generated file's header:

```
//      SpecFlow Version:1.7.1.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:1.7.0.0
//      Runtime Version:4.0.30319.468
```

Now, after installing version 1.8.1, I've got this:

```
//      SpecFlow Version:1.8.1.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:1.8.0.0
//      Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
```

Note the change of the build number from `468` to `239`? I'm wondering where that change of the (.NET) Runtime Version comes from. Checking some dlls under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` showed that they carry the version number `4.0.30319.239` - so how do I "update" (back) to `4.0.30319.468`?

Any help/hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I remember the same thing happened when we updated to SF 1.8.1. You don't need to worry about this in the generated feature files, since they're just comments. SF 1.8.1 still worked for us.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question didn't really concern SpecFlow itself - I didn't expect it not to work, to be honest. I'm just really curious what's up with the Runtime Version numbers :-)